# How to get the className of activeFocusControl in QML ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt, qml, applicationwindow

I try

```
ApplicationWindow {
    onActiveFocusControlChanged: {
    console.log(activeFocusControl)
    console.log(activeFocusControl.objectName)
    }
}
```

ouput:

```
qml: QQuickTextField(0xa6ec00)    //the 'activeFocusControl'
qml:                              //the 'activeFocusControl.objectName'
qml: QQuickButton(0xd7ccb0)
qml:
```

I want to

```
onActiveFocusControlChanged: {
    if (activeFocusControl.className == "QQuickTextField") {
        //do something
    }
    else if (activeFocusControl.className == "QQuickButton") {
        //do something
    }
```

but the "className" method does not exist
so how i can do it?

sorry, my english is pool, and thank you

Comment: As I know there is no way to get class name in QML. But you can use [objectName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#accessing-loaded-qml-objects-by-object-name) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to access the className from qml, so a possible solution is to create a helper from c ++ as shown below:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <QObject>

class Helper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getClassName(QObject *obj) const{
           return obj? obj->metaObject()->className(): "";
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Helper helper;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("helper", &helper);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

then it is used on the QML side:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 270
        y: 47
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField
        x: 220
        y: 169
        text: qsTr("Text Field")
    }

    onActiveFocusControlChanged:  {
        var className = helper.getClassName(activeFocusControl)
        switch(className){
        case "QQuickTextField":
            console.log("I am QQuickTextField")
            break
        case "QQuickButton":
            console.log("I am QQuickButton")
            break
        default:
            console.log("empty")
        }
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47988595).